# Error compiling library fortran libgmxfort (pkgconfig)

Tags: linux, compilation, fortran, environment-variables

I've installed a library (https://github.com/wesbarnett/libgmxfort) called 'libgmxfor' in order to access directly .xtc files, originated into Gromacs package.
Installation was all right, pass tests, requirements also installed w/o problems.
When I tried to compline an example code with `$gfortran -O3 <filename>`:

```
use gmxfort_trajectory

implicit none

type(Trajectory) :: trj
integer :: i, n

call trj%open("traj.xtc", "index.ndx")

n = trj%read_next(10)
do while (n > 0)
    do i = 1, n
        ! do some things with the frames read in
    end do
    n = trj%read_next(10)
end do

call trj%close()
```

And the following error message pops:

```
teste_xtc.f90:1:4:

    1 | use gmxfort_trajectory
      |    1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘gmxfort_trajectory.mod’ for reading at (1): Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
compilation terminated.
```

I gess it could be a problem of environment variable set up but I don't know how to solve it.
Additional info: `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` yields `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`. Into this directory there are 2 files: `libgmxfort.pc  libxdrfile.pc`.

```
$cat libgmxfort.pc

libdir=/usr/local/lib
includedir=/usr/local/include

Name: libgmxfort
Description: Fortran toolkit for analyzing GROMACS simulations
URL: https://github.com/wesbarnett/libgmxfort
Version: 0.4.4
Libs: -L${libdir} -lgmxfort
Cflags: -I${includedir}

$cat libxdrfile.pc

libdir=/usr/local/lib
includedir=/usr/local/include

Name: libxdrfile
Description: Reads/writes compressed trajectory files
URL: https://github.com/wesbarnett/libxdrfile
Version: 2.1.2
Libs: -L${libdir} -lxdrfile
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

And about the content of the directory this files point to here we go:

```
$ls /usr/local/lib
cmake          libgmxfort.so.0.4    libxdrfile.so      libxdrfile.so.2.1.2  pypy2.7    python3.7
libgmxfort.so  libgmxfort.so.0.4.4  libxdrfile.so.2.1  pkgconfig            python2.7  vmd

$ls /usr/local/include
gmxfort_common.mod  gmxfort_trajectory.mod  trr_seek.h  xdrfile_trr.h  xtc_seek.h
gmxfort_index.mod   gmxfort_utils.mod       xdrfile.h   xdrfile_xtc.h
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
$ gfortran teste_xtc.f90 -O3 -I /usr/local/include
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccHuWEGg.o: na função "main":
teste_xtc.f90:(.text.startup+0x4): referência não definida para "__gmxfort_trajectory_MOD___vtab_gmxfort_trajectory_Trajectory"
/usr/bin/ld: teste_xtc.f90:(.text.startup+0x88): referência não definida para "__gmxfort_trajectory_MOD_trajectory_open"
/usr/bin/ld: teste_xtc.f90:(.text.startup+0xa5): referência não definida para "__gmxfort_trajectory_MOD_trajectory_read_next"
/usr/bin/ld: teste_xtc.f90:(.text.startup+0xcd): referência não definida para "__gmxfort_trajectory_MOD_trajectory_read_next"
/usr/bin/ld: teste_xtc.f90:(.text.startup+0xe3): referência não definida para "__gmxfort_trajectory_MOD_trajectory_close"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compilation worked now but an error popped in execution time.

```
$ gfortran teste_xtc.f90 -O3 -I /usr/local/include -lgmxfort 
$ ./a.out  
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libgmxfort.so.0.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[Author's internal reference: seusonho]

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib ./teste2 
Opened traj.xtc for reading.
12878 atoms present in system.
4988 frames present in trajectory file.
Frames saved: 4988
Closed xtc file.

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7fa64442846f in ???
#1  0x7fa64488fe82 in ???
#2  0x7fa64489231a in ???
#3  0x562850988324 in ???
#4  0x56285098817e in ???
#5  0x7fa6444091e2 in ???
#6  0x5628509881bd in ???
#7  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Comment: Have you told gfortran to look in `/usr/local/include` for modules (with `-I` or otherwise)?

Comment: Hi, I did as per your suggestion. Another error message popped now. The output I've placed above at the end of original question. I still don't know what to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to link with the library as well. Add `-lgmxfort` to the compile command line.

Comment: Compilation worked now but an error popped in execution time (I've also added the bellow code into the main text above):
`$ gfortran teste_xtc.f90 -O3 -I /usr/local/include -lgmxfort`
`$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libgmxfort.so.0.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's curious, suggesting that `/usr/local/lib` isn't on the default dynamic library search path (it usually is, but maybe your Linux installation is special). Try something like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib ./a.out`.

Comment: Hi, thanks guys for the help. This last command seems to solve the main issues. In execution time I still had some error but now I support it has to do with the code itself, but not sure. I've placed this last output again the in bottom of main question above, if you can please take a look. Thanks again and have a nice week!